# Skip batch apex script if running

Tags: apex

have two batchable apex scripts that create a dataset for reporting.

- The first walks through a custom object clearing some data elements.
- The second walks through assignments to accumulate new values for the custom object elements.

I have a button on the custom object tab for the users to initiate the process manually and it is scheduled to run at night as well.

- Occasionally a user will initiate the process via the button while it is still running resulting in corrupted data.

I am looking for the best method to stop the first job from running if either of the two jobs are still running. Both jobs are `Batchable` contexts and I am having difficulty how to create a flag and reset it when completed. I would appreciate any and all suggestions.

Comment: did you look at querying `AsyncApexJob` to see if job is still running?

Comment: I did read about that but I tried to query it in Developer Console but I got an error saying invalid sql.  Made me think I did not have permissions.   Can I query it in the  Start and pass a variable to Execute and Finish to skip the processing and call to the second script?  If I define a variable above the start method will it be available in Execute and finish?

Comment: yes to all questions; see Database.Stateful for persistence of variables across start-execute-finish

Comment: Thanks.  One more question: Also what is the field name for the Apex Class Name column so I can use it in the where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A batchable can use a query on `AsyncApexJob` to see if a job is still running under the same class name. [Object Ref doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm?q=AsyncApexJob)

```
public enum AsyncApexJobStatus {
    Holding,Queued,Preparing,Processing,Aborted,Completed,Failed
}
private static final Set<String> inFlightJobStatuses = new Set<String> {
        AsyncApexJobStatus.Holding.name(), 
        AsyncApexJobStatus.Queued.name(),
        AsyncApexJobStatus.Preparing.name(),
        AsyncApexJobStatus.Processing.name()

};



AsyncApexJob[] jobs = [SELECT Id, Status 
                        FROM AsyncApexJob
                        WHERE ApexClass.Name = :myApexClassName AND
                           JobType != 'BatchApexWorker' AND
                           Status IN :inFlightStatuses];
```

Since you haven't provided more details, how you choose to act on the presence of an existing in-flight job varies but typically, if the SOQL is executed within the batchable `start()`, you would do the following:

```
if (!jobs.isEmpty()) {
   System.abortJob(batchableContext.getJobId()); // abort ourselves
   return;
}
// get QueryLocator or Iterable done here
```

The `start()`, each `execute()`, and `finish()` are run in separate transactions and to communicate between these, if the Batchable implements [Database.Stateful](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm?q=Database.Stateful), then the batchable's object variables are available.

Comment: Thanks for the details! The abortJob method should work nicely.   Is there a way to pass back a message to display on the page when the class aborts?  The button is tied to a VF page which calls the apex method to start the batch.

Comment: Not really. If you do the abort in the start() method then NO - as the batchable is async.  You'd need another way to signal the page (say, via a Platform Event that some LWC on the page could subscribe to - or as you are using VF, an action:poller that looked for some value in an object updated by the start() method.  How to signal a VF page from a batchable merits a different question

Comment: No problem.  Again thanks for all the info.